# Is the word liberal used properly in this sentence

Tags: word-usage, american-english

> A friend once told me, when you're lost you're liberal and when you're liberal you can go anywhere

Is "liberal" used properly here?

Comment: Do you have context for the sentence? It definitely isn't right but the intended meaning isn't obvious - my instinct is they mean "liberated" but I'd rather not assume.

Comment: It's impossible to say: liberal is what we call **a loaded word**. But it looks pretty iffy in that sentence. Kind of silly.

Comment: Well, that was the context '' hey, I'm lost. Then she Said '' when you're lost you're liberal and when you're liberal you can go anywhere'' so I do believe she meant to usr it as free and opened, and that makes the question now, can we actually use liberal in context instead of free and opened?

Comment: Perhaps it should be **at liberty**. (Although even that would be a bit odd—because being lost implies nothing like that.) But I can't think of any context where *liberal* would make sense. Barring anything further, I would say that *liberal* is definitely not being used properly.

Answer (score 1):

"liberal" normally means "politically liberal" - the exact connotations of this vary from one country to another: the Liberals are a centrist party in the UK, whereas "liberal" is used to describe the left wing of the Democratic Party in the USA.  Other meanings of "liberal" can be checked in a dictionary.

I suspect the correct word to use would be "free". This can mean "at liberty" (which would be a possible alternative.)